# ¿Como puedo guardar un registro de venta en MySQL recuperando información desde otra tabla

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas de nieves, en el cual el administrador modificará o agregará nuevos productos a la tabla 'productos' la cual se ve a continuación:

| productos |
| --- |
| id_producto |
| nombre |
| cantidad |
| tamano |
| precio_unidad |
| precio_publico |
| descripcion |

En base a esta tabla, tengo una segunda llamada 'nieves' la cual es la siguiente:

| nieves |
| --- |
| id_nieve |
| sabor |
| base |
| tamano |
| precio |
| existencias |
| fecha_venta |
| id_producto |

El vendedor solo podrá llenar los campos de sabor, base y tamano, por lo que requiero recuperar el precio_publico de mi tabla 'productos' e irlo sumando conforme se vayan agregando nuevos productos

Mi interfaz se ve así

[image: Interfaz nieves]

Para agregar una nieve tienen que completar el txt de cantidad ya que esta se le restará al número de existencias que hay en la tabla 'productos' y tambien para hacer el calculo del costo total
pero me gustaria saber como tomar los datos de la tabla productos en base a su tamaño y sabor (ya que dependiendo del sabor tambien hay un cambio de precio) y que esta no me genere conflicto al realizar un conteo de las nieves vendidas en ese momento ya que en el paso 2 doy a conocer el precio total a pagar por los productos

El código que estoy usando en el botón agregar es el siguiente

```
private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCanti.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, rellena la cantidad de nieves");
            }
            else
            {
                int cantNieve = int.Parse(txtCanti.Text);
                string tamNieve = listaTamanos.Text;
                string saborNieve = listaSabores.Text;
                string cantIni;
                string baseNieve = listaBase.Text;
                MySqlConnection conexionBD = Conexion.conex();

                //string pPub = "SELECT p.precio_publico FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN nieves AS n ON p.id_producto = n.id_nieve WHERE p.nombre =  '" + saborNieve + "'";
                //String pPub = "SELECT p.precio_publico, n.sabor FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN FROM nieves AS n ON id_nieve = id_producto WHERE p.nombre = '"+ saborNieve +"'";
                String pPub = "SELECT precio_publico FROM productos WHERE nombre = n.sabor FROM nieves AS n INNER JOIN id_nieve = id_producto WHERE ";//precio_publico
                conexionBD.Open();             
                //string sql = "INSERT INTO nieves (tamano, base, sabor, precio, existencias, fecha_venta) VALUES ('" + tamNieve + "', '" + baseNieve + "', '" + saborNieve + "', '" + Int32.Parse(pPub) + "', '" + cantIni + "', '" + fecha + "')";

                //usar GRID antes de guardar

                //String sql = "INSERT INTO nieves (tamano, base, sabor, precio, existencias, fecha_venta) VALUES ('" + tamNieve + "','" + baseNieve + "','" +  + "','" + precioUnidadProd + "', '" + cantidadPro + "', '" + tamanoProd + "')";                conexionBD.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(pPub, conexionBD);
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado");
                    limpiarNieves();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexionBD.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

En esta parte del código recopilo la información en una sola consulta pero como quiero guardar el precio para sumarlo dependiendo el número de nieves que se vendan en ese momento y la cantidad para eliminarlos de existencias pensé que haciendo consultas independientes  para tomar los datos y usarlos me serviria (esta parte de código es como lo tenia antes, y se que no son las mejores practicas por que es muy repetitivo)

```
private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCanti.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, rellena la cantidad de nieves");
            }
            else
            {
                int cantNieve = int.Parse(txtCanti.Text);
                string tamNieve = listaTamanos.Text;
                string saborNieve = listaSabores.Text;
                string cantIni;
                string baseNieve = listaBase.Text;
                MySqlConnection conexionBD = Conexion.conex();

                string pPub = "SELECT p.precio_publico FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN nieves AS n ON p.id_producto = n.id_nieve WHERE p.nombre =  '" + saborNieve + "'";
                //String pPub = "SELECT p.precio_publico, n.sabor FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN FROM nieves AS n ON id_nieve = id_producto WHERE p.nombre = '"+ saborNieve +"'";
                //String pPub = "SELECT precio_publico FROM productos WHERE nombre = n.sabor FROM nieves AS n INNER JOIN id_nieve = id_producto WHERE ";//precio_publico
                conexionBD.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(pPub, conexionBD);
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cantIni = pPub;
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al buscar: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexionBD.Close();

                }

                String pExis = "SELECT p.cantidad FROM productos AS p INNER JOIN nieves AS n ON p.id_producto = n.id_nieve WHERE p.nombre =  '" + saborNieve + "'";
                conexionBD.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(pExis, conexionBD);
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cantIni = int.Parse(pExis);
                    int c = int.Parse(txtCanti.Text);
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexionBD.Close();

                }

                string sql = "INSERT INTO nieves (tamano, base, sabor, precio, existencias, fecha_venta) VALUES ('" + tamNieve + "', '" + baseNieve + "', '" + saborNieve + "', '" + Int32.Parse(pPub) + "', '" + cantIni + "', '" + fecha + "')";

                //usar GRID antes de guardar

                //String sql = "INSERT INTO nieves (tamano, base, sabor, precio, existencias, fecha_venta) VALUES ('" + tamNieve + "','" + baseNieve + "','" +  + "','" + precioUnidadProd + "', '" + cantidadPro + "', '" + tamanoProd + "')";                conexionBD.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexionBD);
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado");
                    limpiarNieves();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conexionBD.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

En este código lo que intentaba hacer es recuperar por separado tanto el valor de existencias como de precio_publico de la tabla productos

Comment: Aqui no se hacen los deberes de nadie, te recomiendo que pongas en ejemplo minimo de tu consulta sql.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: El tamaño afecta al precio y de que manera, o nieves de distinto tamaño son productos distintos

Comment: Perdonen  aqui esta como realizo la consulta y la obtención de datos

Comment: @Francisco Las nieves dependiendo el tamaño cuestan de 35 a 170 pesos (solo se manejan 4 tamaños) y de igual manera dependiendo del sabor (si es común se deja el precio de 35 a 170 y si es uno como Nutella se agregan 5 pesos más), y pues a pesar de que sean nieves pueden tener distinta base por eso lo puse diferente

Comment: @Francisco es una usuaria nueva. A las buenas también se puede guiar a la gente. Y con menos comentarios, que no es un chat.

Comment: @LauraSofiaDelgadoDiaz Bienvenidx a SOes. Lo que intentas es claro y es una aproximación válida. ¿Qué problema te da correr el código de esta forma? Procura responder a los comentarios que piden aclaraciones, yendo siempre a [edit] la pregunta y añadiendo la info que te piden

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por responder, ya actualicé nuevamente la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string pPub = "SELECT p.precio_publico FROM productos AS p 
                        WHERE p.nombre =  '" + saborNieve + "' and
                              p.tamano='" + tamNieve  + "'";
```

Entendiendo que para un sabor( que es el nombre del producto) y un tamaño existe un precio unico.

```
            conexionBD.Open();
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(pPub, conexionBD);
                var precio=(float)comando.ExecuteScalar();
                
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al buscar: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexionBD.Close();

            }
```

Usar ExecuteScalar para obtener un único valor devuelto por el comando o la consulta

listaTotal.Text=$"{cantNieve * precio}";

Comment: muchas gracias, si pude resolver mi problema